# Object isn't seen as function React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

i have the following code

```
 9 |     const [personS, setpersonS] = useState([]);
  10 |  const [loaded, setloaded] = useState(false);
  11 | 
> 12 |  let location = useLocation();
     | ^  13 |  const linkFollowers =
  14 |    location && location.state && location.state.followers
  15 |      ? location.state.followers
```

but brings an error of "***TypeError: Object(...) is not a function***". Can anyone help me out on how to solve this.

Comment: We need to see more of your code.

Comment: Is `useLocation` the hook from the `react-router` package? Or is that some custom hook you've written? Need more details

Comment: Please share a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the code you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put it in a function like

```
const MyComp = (props) =>{
  const [personS, setpersonS] = useState([]);
  const [loaded, setloaded] = useState(false);

  let location = useLocation(); //<--- put this in a Hook
}

export default MyComp
```

Comment: thanks this help me find the solution